# Bad_alloc problem

Tags: c++, exception, memory, memory-leaks

my program throws a  std::bad_alloc. After debugging it, I found out it is thrown in code

```
curFinalBucket->points.push_back(p);
```

where points is a `vector<PPointT>` . Before the code line, `curFinalBucket` is initialized as follows.

```
PFinalBucket curFinalBucket;
curFinalBucket = (FinalBucket*)malloc(sizeof(FinalBucket));
```

Strange thing is that if I simply put the above code in `main`, no exception. But when I put it as follows,

```
void mergeBucket(map<BucketT, vector<PPointT>, Comp> *pMap, IntT numFinalBuckets)
{
...
PFinalBucket curFinalBucket;
curFinalBucket = (FinalBucket*)malloc(sizeof(FinalBucket));
curFinalBucket->points.push_back(p);
}

int testLoadBalancedLSH(IntT num_fbuckets, RealT avgNumPossessedTerms, IntT np, IntT d, char* dataFile)
{
...
mergeBucket(&mapstore, num_fbuckets);
}

int main(int nargs, char **args) {
...
testLoadBalancedLSH(atoi(args[1]), 0.01 * atoi(args[2]), atoi(args[2]), atoi(args[3]), args[4]);
}
```

it will throw the exception in question. Any ideas what this could be all about? thanks in advance.

Comment: PPointT p = map_it->second[i]; where map_it is map<BucketT, vector<PPointT> >::const_iterator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is you are creating curFinalBucket with malloc. This does not call the constructor so the internal `vector<PPointT>` is not initialized when you try to use it.

I guess FinalBucket is something like:

```
 class FinalBucket{
    public:
       vector<PPointT> points;
 }
```

`points` needs an initialization that is not happening because FinalBucket constructor is not being called and `vector<PPointT>` constructor is not being called either.

You are just allocating memory, but you need the constructors to be called for initialization to take place.

The only way around this is to use **new** to allocate FinalBucket.

```
PFinalBucket curFinalBucket;
curFinalBucket = new FinalBucket();
curFinalBucket->points.push_back(p);
```

Comment: Yes, this triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: but following code works fine. how to explain?

`int main()
{
 PFinalBucket curFinalBucket;
 curFinalBucket = (FinalBucket*)malloc(sizeof(FinalBucket));
 printf("s%d\n", curFinalBucket->vec.size());
 PPointT p = (PPointT)malloc(sizeof(PointT));
 p->i = 9;
 curFinalBucket->vec.push_back(p);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Richard, the code you are using does `never` initialize `points`. The fact that it appears to work in your `main` example does not mean is right, it is undefined behaviour, I suggest you run yout `main` example through valgrind to see it for yourself, or just use `points` on couple of thousands iterations. You `HAVE` to use `new`.

Comment: @Richard: undefined behavior may be anything. It might work or it might not, depending on the phase of the moon and various other factors.

Comment: @Arkaitz: I would upvote your answer if you mentioned a solution.

Comment: @Arkaitz: allocating with `new` is not the **only** way, though it is probably the **proper** way.

Comment: @larsmans, sure, you could use malloc and then placement new, or somehow call the constructor yourself, but that was not the point of the question, was it?

Comment: @Arkaitz: no, and I gave you a +1 for this answer. But I often find that novice C++ programmers overuse `new` and `malloc`; possibly a pointer isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`(FinalBucket*)malloc(sizeof(FinalBucket));` allocates memory for an object of the size of a `FinalBucket`, but it doesn't actually create a final bucket. You should use `new FinalBucket()` for this.

Also, as a note on style, hiding pointers behind macros/typedefs like `PFinalBucket` makes your code harder to read. Just write `FinalBucket *` instead, it's much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **new FinalBucket** to allocate dynamic memory instead of malloc. The new operator will call the constructor of **FinalBucket**, in which vector which be initialized.